# How is a boomi process stored?

Tags: netsuite, boomi

I am exploring boomi for now, I have a bit of working experience in Mulesoft. In Mulesoft, you can view the flow that you create in XML format in Anypoint Platform, and it can be viewed in the disk as well. Is there any such file created for Boomi processes? If yes, where are they located and how can I view them?

I can see that in the revision history of any component on the Build canvas in AtomSphere, you can view the XML of the component. Can I view the backend code for the whole process somehow?

Comment: You can view the XML in the Revision History of a Process. But it isn't of much use to you as it includes mostly visual/shape data. You can also view it on the Molecule's/Atom's configured File storage. I don't know of any way of seeing the "backend code" for a process as such, it might even be interpreted by the Java engine, not compiled.

The bigger questions you probably need to answer are Why you want to. Boomi is not (for better or worse) a traditional development environment where seeing the code, or using traditional approaches to version control, etc. are all that useful.